# Input into C console app returns baffling combination of conditional output responses

Tags: c, command-line, io, console-application

Wrote this test code to try to sniff out a bug in a larger project.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char newCalculation;

    printf("Enter a Y/N value for newCalculation");
    scanf("%c", &newCalculation);

    do
    {
         printf("Yes! %c", newCalculation);
    }while( tolower( newCalculation ) == 'y' );

    if( tolower( newCalculation ) == 'n' )
    {
        printf("Nope.");
    }

    while( tolower( newCalculation ) != 'n' && tolower( newCalculation ) != 'y' )
    {
        printf("This is not a valid response.\n Please enter \"Y\" if you want to do another calculation, or enter \"N\" to exit.");
        scanf("%c", &newCalculation);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Inputting 'y' at the command line is supposed to return

```
Yes! y
```

Inputting 'n' at the command line is supposed to return

```
No. n
```

Any other input is supposed to issue an "invalid" response and a new input prompt.

However, when I enter 'y', I get:

```
Yes!  This is not a valid response.  Please enter "y" if you want to do another calculation, or enter "N" to exit.
```

What is causing this?  It's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `scanf(" %c", &newCalculation);` (notice the space before `%c`), though I would use `getchar()` for getting single character.

Also, you flow doesn't actually makes sense in here:

```
 do {
     printf("Yes! %c", newCalculation);
 } while( tolower( newCalculation ) == 'y' );
```

E. g. when I type `y` in a corrected program, it obviously loops infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

You program outputs `Yes! y` infinitely if the input is 'y'

and outputs ´`Yes! nNope.` if the input is 'n'.

The output is `Yes! xThis is not a valid response.
 Please enter "Y" if you want to do another calculation, or enter "N" to exit. This is not a valid response.
 Please enter "Y" if you want to do another calculation, or enter "N" to exit.`

if your input is not y || n.

Your program is totaly wrong and will never do what you expect it to.

Here is version that does what you want

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char newCalculation;

    printf("Enter a Y/N value for newCalculation");
    scanf(" %c", &newCalculation);

    do {
      if (tolower(newCalculation) == 'y') {
      printf("Yes! %c", newCalculation);
      break;
      } else  if( tolower( newCalculation ) == 'n' ) {
       printf("Nope.");
       break;
        } else  {
      printf("This is not a valid response.\n Please enter \"Y\" if you want to do another calculation, or enter \"N\" to exit.");
      scanf(" %c", &newCalculation);
    }
    } while (1);
    return 0;
}
```